# Continuity of Vector Valued Functions from $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\triangle=\{(t_0,t_1,t_2)\in \mathbb{R^3}:t_0+t_1+t_2=1$ and $t_i\geq0$ for $i=0,1,2\}$. Prove that the function $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\longrightarrow \triangle$ defined by
$f(x_1,x_2) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  (x_1,x_2-x_1,1-x_2)  & \mbox{if } x_1 \leq x_2 \\
  (x_2,x_1-x_2,1-x_1) & \mbox{if } x_2 \leq x_1 
 \end{array}
\right.$
is continuous.

$My Approach:$ I have use the sequential criterion to prove this. Choose $(c_1,c_2)\in [0,1]\times [0,1] $ arbitrary. Take any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ converging to$(c_1,c_2)$. This implies $x_n\longrightarrow c_1$ and $y_n\longrightarrow c_2$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$.This will imply that $f(x_n,y_n)\longrightarrow f(c_1,c_2)$. Hence $f$ is continuous.

$Question:$ Is my approach is correct? 
Also, we need to prove $f(A\times B)$ is closed if $A$ and $B$ are closed subset of $[0,1]$.
Please Help.

Comment: No, the sequences are not useful here, they do not make it possible to show continuity more simply. The function being defined differently on $U=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 | x<y\}$ and $V=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 | x>y\}$, you should check at the "seam" i.e. $D=\{(x,x)| x\in [0,1]\}$. On $U$ or $V$, you show continuity easily by considering the restrictions of f to these sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2|x<y\}$, $V=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2|x>y\}$ and $D=\{(x,x)| x\in[0,1]\}$

The function $f$ is continuous on $U$ and $V$ because the coordinate functions of the restrictrions $f_{|U}$ and $f_{|V}$ are polynomial.

Let $x\in[0,1]$. Show the continuity of $f$ at $(x,x)$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let's define $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$.

Let $(x_1,x_2)\in [0,1]^2$ such that $(x_1,x_2) \in\mathcal{B}((x,x),\delta)$. We have

$\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+(x_2-x)^2}<\delta$, thus

$|x_1-x|\leq  \sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+(x_2-x)^2}<\delta$ and $|x_2-x|<\delta$

Moreover $|x_1-x_2| \leq |x_1-x+x-x_2|\leq |x_1-x|+|x-x_2|<2\delta$

If $(x_1,x_2)\in U$ then

$||f(x_1,x_2)-f(x,x)||=||(x_1-x,x_2-x_1,-x_2+x)||=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2+(x-x_2)^2}$

$\leq \sqrt{\delta^2+4\delta^2+\delta^2}\leq \sqrt{6}\delta<\varepsilon$

idem if $(x_1,x_2)\in V$ (by switching $x_1$ and $x_2$)

To prove that $f(A\times B)$ is closed, we can use the theorem of the image of a compact by a  continuous function.